# can't access stored procedure values in foreach loop in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

Can't Access column values of SQL select statement of Stored Procedure in foreach loop 
**This Error occure when run code**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUCcy.png)

**This is stored Procedure**

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[getAuthorBooks]
@id int
as
Begin
select BookName,Paid from Book where AuthorId=@id
End
```

**This is C# code**
 public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {

```
        Author auth = new Author();
        parhowDBEntities d=new parhowDBEntities();
        var data = d.getAuthorBooks(9).ToList();
        int x=data.Count;
        ViewBag.AB = data;

        Author auth2 = new Author();

        auth2 = auth.GetEntity(id);

        return View(auth2);
    }
```

**This is View Code**

```
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.AB)
        {
            @item.BookName
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first, you should cast ViewBag.ViewBag.AB to List. And then you can access column like below:

```
@foreach (var item in  (List<Author>)ViewBag.AB )
        {
            <td> @item.BookName </td>
        }
```

Comment: i fetch data from multiple tables using join so this is not work for me.

Comment: So you can create a model with all property you need, my friend. And then, can access easily.